# Select input pixel of image by mouseclick in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement a tracking program using the Mean-Shift algorithm in Matlab. The idea is that, given the first frame of one video, the user can click on top of any object he wants and the program will track it all through the video sequence. I have already implemented and working the tracking part, but I am having problems giving the user the possibility to click on top of the image to select the initial pixel for the tracking algorithm.

I have thought about `input` function, but I don't know how to make it work. How can I display an image and click on top of a pixel and get its coordinates [x,y] to initialize the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ginput](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) (Graphical input from mouse or cursor)

Read any image and show them using [imread](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) and [imshow](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html)

```
h = imread('hestain.png');         % any input image
imshow(h);
```

Get the coordinates using [ginput](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html), where the input argument corresponds to the number of user clicks recorded.

```
[x,y] = ginput(1);                 % getting coordinates from user
```

To obtain the pixel value, we need to pass the coordinates as indices of the image. To do this, the output arguments from the `ginput` which are `double` by default, must be converted to `unsigned integers`.

Also, `x` and `y` represents horizontal and vertical by default.  But matlab syntax takes first dimension as **rows** (number of horizontal lines calculated **vertically**). Hence `y` value is passed as first dimension. Similarly `x` value as second dimension.

```
pixelValue = h(uint8(y),uint8(x)); % using coordinates as indices
```